# Filling a List<T> from a class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, console-application

Since a few weeks i'am following a evening class for C#.net.
I am trying to create a console application that asks for one or multiple persons firstname, lastname, age etc. It is possible to give in multiple records.

And put this in a List and afterwards print the list of persons to the console.

```
    public class Program
{
    public static List<Person> _people = new List<Person>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Naam: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Achternaam: ");
            string lastname = Console.ReadLine();

            Person person = new Person(name, lastname);
            _people.Add(person);

            Console.Write("Would you like to add another person?");


        } while (Console.ReadLine()=="J");

        PrintDetails();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    static void PrintDetails()
    {
        foreach (Person person in _people)
        {
            Console.Write(person._name +" ");
            Console.WriteLine(person._lastname);
        }
    }
```

and my class:

```
    public class Person
{
    public string _name;
    public string _lastname;

    public Person(string name, string lastname)
    {
        _name = name;
        _lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

I feel like there is an easier more "correct" way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: That's pretty correct code, I'm not sure there is a better way or that I've seen better code in beginner classes

Comment: probably best moving this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Code looks OK, no problem with it, move this to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry that I posted this in the wrong section.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty much "it".

You are using a console, so you have to use a do..while loop for the input and you use it corectly.

And you are using foreach for the printing.

I can not see a single line you could save.

Just one minor nitpick. Those fieldnames with a underscore: Usually they are reserved for non-public variables. When using properties, you need a backing field. And it is **fundamentally** important that you do access the backing field in any class code (except the property handlers)! Putting a underscore in front of the backing fields guarantees there are no mixups between the property "Name" and the field "_Name".

Indeed many prefer to just use auto implement properties, so they can not accidentally access the backing field. Or going as far as hinding the field values in a Dictionary. Just to eliminate any chance to use the fields by accident.

In your case the fields are public, so a underscore serves no purpose.

Edit: You can actualyl save one line!

```
Console.Write(person._name +" ");
Console.WriteLine(person._lastname);
```

can be compressed to:

```
Console.WriteLine(person._name + " " + person._lastname);
```

However I would not nessesarily advise it. Having two field or property accesses in one line can make debugging hard (see "Reference not set to an instance of object"). And chances are the JiT compiler will notice that and optimize it outside of debug builds anyway.

Comment: Huh, I read an underscore and assumed private. I am pretty sure the OP hasn't seen properties just yet though

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I noticed it because I could not see any property handlers or a ToString() function, so they had to be public to be printed.

Comment: Ye thats my bad that used the underscores. Will remember for next time.
Thanks for the help!